# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite rule not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have my wordpress in a sub-folder on my domain with a `.htacess` file on the root which does all the redirecting.

i want to do a redirect, the site IP to WWW. which works for the main site on the root but not for the sub-folder which is  Wordpress.

iv got a feeling wordpress is overwriting this some where?

this is what iv used in root `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP.IP.IP.IP [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NAME.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this does not work for the wordpress sub-folder
iv even tried to copy this into the `.htaccess` file in the WP root folder but still not work

Comment: You mentioned that you tried copying the .htaccess to subfolder? What error did you get? After moving the .htaccess file, did you try accessing your blog using the domain name instead of IP? Does it work?

Comment: yes i did try moving the root .htaceess to the subfolder where WP is but nothing changed WP still worked but redirecting didnt.

Comment: I'm sure redirect didn't work, why else you would ask for help. :) anyway, I wanted to know what was the url in browser when it didn't work. Check the upadted answer, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your Wordpress wp-admin panel there is a setting:

```
Settings -> General -> WordPress address (URL)
```

and

```
Settings -> General -> Blog address (URL)
```

Make sure to update them to `http://www.domain.com/subfolder` then it will start working.

### UPDATE (Based on your comments)

Use following .htaccess inside WP install folder '/blog'

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^/?$ /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP\.IP\.IP\.IP$
RewriteRule . http://www.NAME.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: HI @Anubhava WP is working and the general setting URL you mentioned above are correct. what the problem is, is that you can access the blog using http //ip.ip.ip./blog/ which i DO NOT WANT i want it to redirect to w.name.com/blog/

Comment: Yes I know your wordpress is working but pls understand that's the one what causing this behavior to you :) Whatever you define in those 2 properties I mentioned in my answer, wordpress will treat that as **BASE** wordpress URL. Everytime wordpress `blog/index.php` runs it uses that property. So no mater what you have in .htaccess before that it will redirect to the URL defined in `Settings -> General -> WordPress address (URL)`

Comment: Am still not sure what you mean!! what you mention at the top i have the full url (domain name not IP adr) but like i said i can still access the site using the IP/blog/ but if i go the main site with IP then it redirects to w.name.com.  so how can i get WP to always be on w.name.com/blog and nothing else??

Comment: What I meant was that if you have `http://w.name.com/blog` set in these 2 settings: `Settings -> General -> WordPress address (URL)` and `Settings -> General -> Blog address (URL)` then Wordpress will automatically make start of your URL as `http://w.name.com/blog` even if you enter `http://IP-address/blog`

Comment: Ok but its not! i can still access WP through 'http: // IP-address/blog'

Comment: @Daniel Morton: Finally I was able to reproduce your issue on my end. Where `http://IP-addr/blog/wp-admin` was being redirected to `http://w.name.com/blog/wp-admin` but `http://w.name.com/blog/` was **NOT**. I had to modify WP folder's .htaccess to fix that. Please see my answer in **update** section above.

Answer (score 0):

**.htsccess file overrides the .htaccess files in the parent directories.** In your case, the WordPress blog directory has a .htaccess file which is overriding the .htaccess file in the root. This is why you see it working for the root, but not for the subdfolder, say, /blog.

You should not be replacing the .htaccess created by WordPress. `Add` the rewrite rules in the existing .htacess file in the subdirectory and make sure this is the first rule in the file(i.e inside `<if ...>` block). If you are using WP Super Cache or similar plugin, make sure you create a new if block above the rules created by the plugins and leave the WordPress created `<if ...>` block intact.

`<edit>`

In your root folder,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP\.IP\.IP\.IP [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NAME.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In your WP directory(WPDIR) .htaccess file before any other rule,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP\.IP\.IP\.IP [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NAME.com/WPDIR/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Of course, put it inside the `<if ...>` block and turn the RewriteEngine on.

Comment: done this already and didnt work! still keeps the IP url not redirecting to www.

Comment: can you put the entire .htaccess file from your blog folder in your question for inspection?